# flandmark library in dev c++ for feature point detection

Tags: c++, feature-detection

How to include flandmark library in dev c++? I need to find landmark points for eye.

There are no proper example for using flanmark in dev c++. When i included the header files in the project directory i still get linkage error.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is still no official support for generating project for dev c++ in CMake. However, you can of course still use it. From your question it is not clear whether you have compiled flandmark library already and now want to create an external project in dev c++ using the library or if you want to compile flandmark library itself using dev c++.

If you have already successfully compiled flandmark and want to use it in external project, then besides setting the include directory and include the header files, you also need to specify linking directory and link flandmark libary to your project. See e.g. the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/uricamic/flandmark/blob/master/matlab_toolbox/mex/CMakeLists.txt) line 65 file for getting the idea what to include and what to link.

In case you want to use dev c++ for compiling the flandmark library, you need to link the OpenCV libraries and includes and specify the include directory with flandmark headers. For the OpenCV on linux works the command:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

at the end of the g++ line.